# What is the meaning of @* operator in asp.net.mvc?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, comments

I am a newbie to ASP.NET MVC razor engine.

I would like to know the meaning/purpose of using `@*` before the html fragment in cshtml code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its a comment

```
@* this is commented code in a .cshtml file*@
```

Similar to this in a .cs file

```
/*this is commented code in a .cs file*/
```

Answer (score 4):

This is used to comment the code

```
@* Your code here to comment *@
```

The visual studio keyboard shortcut :
 select the section you want comment and press : <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will comment code.
 and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> will uncomment the code.

For those who are looking for `.aspx view engine` pages.

```
<%-- Your code here to comment --%>
```

Comment: You assume of course that he is using Visual Studio

Comment: @AshleyMedway Yes of course. I've edited my answer little bit.

Answer (score 2):

It marks the start of a [comment](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-server-side-comments-with-razor). It's closed with the corresponding *@ sign

Answer (score 2):

> What is the meaning of @* operator in asp.net.mvc?

It has nothing to do with ASP>NET MVC. It is specific to Razor View Engine. It serves as to comment specific part of code or markup which is skipped in output.

So if you do

```
@* Some Tags or Code *@
```

It will just be a comment at server-side. Additionally, this syntax indicates that the Razor parser should ignore everything within that block and treat it like it isn’t there at all (meaning nothing is ever executed, there is no performance overhead at runtime, and nothing is sent down to the client).

Comment: So is there any other possibility to use the Razor view engine with? Isn't the razor view engine a ASP.NET-View-Engine for VB and C#?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Razor can also be used just like T4 templates. It is just the default View Engine in MVC. Every view engine has different commenting styles. e.g. FormsViewEngine has `<%....%>`.

Comment: Ahh okay - Didn't know that. Thanks +1